# Excel How I can delete everything in a cell except the content within specific html tag?

Tags: excel, phpexcel

My Excel sheet has over 700 rows and in the second column I have Product description in html code. I need to extract the specific value which is always in the ....

```
<div class="something">
   <p><strong>Content to remove</strong></p>
   <h1>Content to remove</h1>
   <p>Content to remove</p>
   <h1 class="modelaut">CONTENT TO KEEP</h1>
   <p>Content to remove</p>...
</div>
```

The "CONTENT TO KEEP" is in different position in each row but always in the H1 tag with specific class="modelaut"

Thanks for your Help :)

Comment: does it have to be vba? a formula will work as well. And if it has to be vba, please show your code attempts. (see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: @Scott Holtzman Thanks. No need to be VBA, if it could be done with formular will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following formula works on data and problem as written:

```
=MID(C1,FIND(">",C1,FIND("<h1 class",C1)+1)+1,FIND("</h1",C1,FIND("<h1 class",C1)+1)-FIND(">",C1,FIND("<h1 class",C1)+1)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks your example is working. Since there are multiple h1 tags with different classes I had modified the code and replaced double quotes by single quotes. The final formular which works now is =MID(A1;FIND(">";A1;FIND("<h1 class='modelaut'";A1)+1)+1;FIND("</h1";A1;FIND("<h1 class='modelaut'";A1)+1)-FIND(">";A1;FIND("<h1 class='modelaut'";A1)+1)-1)

Answer (score 0):

with this in cell **A1**:

```
hfewyuifgd<h1876yhfr4>TREASURE</h1vnc>xv67t4gehsd
```

This formula:

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,FIND(">",A1,FIND("<h1",A1))+1,99990),FIND("<",MID(A1,FIND(">",A1,FIND("<h1",A1))+1,99990))-1)
```

will return:

TREASURE

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works fine for your example but in my case I didn't get a value out. Maybe its because of the H1 Tag is multiple times in the content. There is only one H1 Tag with the class"modelaut" which I need. All other need to be deleted. Bun I think it's the right way. Lets modify your example how I need TREASURE. hfewyui<h1>hfjhjfhj</h1><p>hfjhjfhj</p><h1 class="modelaut">TREASURE</h1><p>gfhhg</p><h1>hfjhjfhj</h1>fhfdfhdgehsd

Answer (score 0):

The Code woulde be like this.

```
Sub transString()
    Dim vDB, vSplit1, vSplit2
    Dim rngDB As Range, i As Long
    Set rngDB = Range("b1", Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    vDB = rngDB
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        vSplit1 = Split(vDB(i, 1), "<h1 class=" & Chr(34) & "modelaut" & Chr(34) & ">")
        vSplit2 = Split(vSplit1(1), "</h1>")
        vDB(i, 1) = "<h1 class=" & Chr(34) & "modelaut" & Chr(34) & ">" & vSplit2(0) & "</h1>"
    Next i
    rngDB = vDB
End Sub
```

Comment: it seems that your example replace all with "". How to keep <h1 class="modelaut">CONTENT TO KEEP</h1>? Thanks

Comment: @AndyJJDek'noi:  I modified my code. It will work if there is allways the tag <h1 class="modelaut">.